# Can you increase the size of a VHDX in Hyper-V at a later time?

Tags: hyper-v, vhd, hyper-v-2012

I have a Hyper-V 2012 server with a 2GB disk.

Currently, there is 50GB free on this disk as the remainder is assigned to a VHDX.

I need to migrate a Windows Server Installation into a new copy of Windows on a new VM.
If I create a new VM on the disk that has 50GB left (so a new VHDX with say, 45GB), once I have fully migrated the original VHDX and deleted it, can I expand the size of the VHDX?

Sorry if I explained that badly! Very new to Hyper-V!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can expand a vhdx file. Please read the following link. It has a step-by-step (uuh baby! haha) tutorial about how to perform that action

link: http://virtualizationreview.com/blogs/everyday-virtualization/2012/12/expand-vhdx-disk.aspx

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If your Hyper-V host is running Windows Server 2012 R2, you can resize a VHD that is attached to a virtual SCSI controller while the VM is running.  You can do this through the user interface, or with the Resize-VirtualDisk PowerShell cmdlet.

If the host is older than that, you need to stop the VM or dismount the disk and then resize it using the UI or the Resize-VHD cmdlet.